# Issues when installing AspxCommerce onto GoDaddy Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, sageframe

I have been up all night trying to figure it out and when I try and install AspxCommerce onto my GoDaddy server. I have ran across multiple issues when trying to install this, all of the answers have been found after long research although for This last issue I am getting Configuration Error saying that I do not have any connection to 'SageFrameConnectionString'. Does anybody have any thoughts on how I should go about doing this including the necessary steps to get there?

PS: Everything works great when installed locally..
[image]

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SageFrameSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="SageFrameConnectionString" applicationName="SageFrame" name="SageFrameSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add applicationName="SageFrame" name="SageFrameWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

connectionstring.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="SageFrameConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;Connect Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Post the exact error, show the related code and configuration. Also, we don't need to know the history of your app or how long you've worked on it. Keep your question concise, but still communicate the things we *need* to know.

Comment: This is the only error I usually work with, could you please elaborate more on which error log you may be talking about please. I have uploaded the web.config file.

Comment: You missed the "concise" part if my last comment. We dont need the whole configuration file, just the bits related to the connection string.

Comment: You need to post the contents of `connectionstring.config`. Remove any passwords. Also, remove all the extraneous information from the `web.config` you posted, we only need to see the stuff related to connection strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is not a  `AspxCommerce` problem. It's a GoDaddy server problem.
GoDaddy doesnt allow roles unless you use `LocalSqlServer` as your membership provider connection string.For GoDaddy you have couple of change in `AspxCommerce` .

In `connectionstring.config` file :

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourCatlog;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="ID";Password="PSWD";Connect Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

And In library go to `SageFrame.Common\Setting\SystemSetting.cs` on Declaration section :

replace

```
public static string SageFrameConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SageFrameConnectionString"].ToString();
```

with

```
public static string SageFrameConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString();
```

*Note : Don't forget to rebuild library.*